# Javascript - Color example code

Tags: javascript, plugins

Is there a javascript plugin available that will color example code to make it look as it does in a text editor? Using the php.net prinf page as an example, I want to convert this:

```
<code>
    <?php<br>
        $num = 5;<br>
        $location = 'tree';<br>
        $format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';<br>
        printf($format, $num, $location);<br>
    ?>
</code>
```

to this

```
<code>
<span style="color: #000000">
    <span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php<br>$num&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">5</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">;<br></span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">$location&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #DD0000">'tree'</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">;<br><br></span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">$format&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #DD0000">'There&nbsp;are&nbsp;%d&nbsp;monkeys&nbsp;in&nbsp;the&nbsp;%s'</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">;<br></span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">printf</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">(</span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">$format</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">$num</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">$location</span>
    <span style="color: #007700">);<br></span>
    <span style="color: #0000BB">?&gt;</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Use `<pre>` instead of `<code>` and get rid of the `<br>`'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

Comment: This is what Stack Overflow uses.

Comment: Perfect. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cloudhead/hijs

https://github.com/rpflorence/hilite

Neither depend on a library.

---

Edit: Sorry, thought you wanted to highlight JavaScript (read too fast).  `hilite` still needs PHP added as a language, but you could add it.  Here's a solid one:

http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: Err...unless I'm missing something here, both examples you provide *are libraries* in that they are both included files, no?

Comment: No different than google-code-prettify, include the JS file, include the CSS file, and you're off and running.  I was just pointing out that neither depends on jQuery or MooTools, etc. (since many do, for no reason)

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty difficult without a library... but not much too difficult. You could easily do most of it with regular expressions such as:

```
\$\w+
```

Which would match all variables. Of course, you'd have to filter out those within single-quoted strings. So the basic strategy is - use regex as much as possible, then filter out the exceptions (such as escaping) using manual string parsing with loops. Just look at the methods of the `String` type - you'll use `charAt()` and `insert()` probably for the manual manipulation, and `String.search()` for the regular expressions...